# Move stock availability position in Woocommerce single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Can someone help me find a way to change the stock position on the product page?
Is there a hook for this? Or is there another way?

Comment: No proper details provided, it will be difficult for community members to provide you a solution. Your question should be in detailed. What you trying to achive, what source code you have tried and what you are exactly looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a hook for this?

No, unfortunately as it is hardcoded inside the woocommerce template.

Probably a little late as an answer, but if someone else looks for this, here is an answer from another post:

[woocommerce stock notification priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664561/woocommerce-stock-notification-priority)

Some suggestion from me would be to make a folder inside your child theme of woocommerce so that you will not loose any of the updates.
You can find a more clear answer, straight from woocommerce, here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Also the folders that are mentioned in the utl above can be found inside this firectory path in your server: wp-content -> plugins -> woocommerce -> templates -> single-product -> add-to-cart

Answer (score 0):

you can either change the position of excerpt and other content to the bottom of SKU using hooks like [CHANGE POSITION](https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/reorder-content-woocommerce-product-page/). OR you can also cut & paste the code in stock.php under single-product folder to any other file where you want to show the sku of product like price.php/meta.php/title.php etc...